# React - Reference a component using a string

Tags: reactjs

I need to call a component by using a string that is the same as the component name.

Is there a way to do this without using switch or mapping the strings to the components, which I am able to do currently.

I tried this, but it doesn't work, although this [article](https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9) uses a similar approach.

```
render() {
     let CompName = 'SelectComponent';
     return <CompName />
}
```

This is just an example. The strings (component names) will be defined in an config file, which holds properties for several input fields that need to be rendered.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to use a string instead of mapping the components references?

Comment: You'd need to load those components first, sounds like you're looking for dynamic import or require.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strings for built-in elements (`div`, `span`, ...) but if you want to use a custom component, you need a reference to the component variable.

You can put all your components in an object and get the component variable with the help of the component name.

**Example**

```js
function Foo() {
  return <div> Foo </div>;
}
function Bar() {
  return <div> Bar </div>;
}

const components = { Foo, Bar };

function App(props) {
  const { regularTag: RegularTag, componentTag } = props;
  const Component = components[componentTag];

  return (
    <div>
      <Component />
      <RegularTag> Baz </RegularTag>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App componentTag={"Foo"} regularTag={"div"} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is the same thing he's currently doing which is to map the objects properties to _components_, the only thing changing here is that we'd be accessing the mapped components differently. I do think it's a valid answer because you're clarifying that if it's a string it needs to be an HTML tag. Maybe it would be good to remark in your answer that this is not possible for custom components?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get to is calling an object property via string

```
const Component1 = ()=><h1>This is component 1</h1>
const Component2 = () => <h1>This is component 2</h1>

const obj = {
 component1: <Component1 />,
 component2: <Component2 />
}

render(obj["component2"], document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this without using switch or mapping the strings to the components

There is no way because the framework doesn't have a way to associate component function names with components.

There should be a map that maps components to their names, e.g.:

```
import Foo from './Foo';
import Bar from './Bar';

const componentsMap = { Foo, Bar };

...

let CompName = 'Foo';
return <componentsMap[CompName] />
```

The workflow can be improved with a decorator, especially for class components:

```
const componentsMap = {};

const mapComponent = name => Comp => {
  name = name || Comp.displayName;
  if (!name)
    throw new Error('no comp name');

  return componentsMap[name] = Comp;
}

...

@mapComponent()
class Foo extends Component {
  static displayName = 'Foo';
  ...
}

const Bar = mapComponent('Bar')(props => ...);
```

Component name can be moved to static property like `displayName` but cannot be avoided because function `name` property is mangled during minification and cannot be relied on.

Comment: I'm currently using a map, in an object. So I guess that's the best thing option at this time. Thanks for the response.